# Multiple youtube iframes play play this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
<a id="play-video" href="#">Play Video</a><br />

<iframe id="video" width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9B7te184ZpQ?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

and then this jquery which plays the video:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#play-video').on('click', function(ev) {

    $("#video")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
    ev.preventDefault();

  });
});
```

How can I modify the jquery:

```
$("#video")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
```

So that it only plays the selected where I would have multiple iframes?

Comment: What do you mean by "selected"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your video id to another. Ex #video1, #video to control exactly what video you wanna play or wrap that button and video in a div. Then change your code to

```
<div>
<a id="play-video" href="#">Play Video</a><br />
<iframe id="video" width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9B7te184ZpQ?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

And this

```
$().ready(function () {
    $('.play-video').click(function () {
    //alert($(this).parent().children('#video').attr(src));
        $(this).parent().children('#video').attr('src', function () {
        return this + "&autoplay=1";
    });
  });
});
```

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/minhthanh/acg8e7f1/

Comment: I don't want to ID hardcode it. I'm looking for a dynamic what to do this ... like [THIS]

Comment: Sorry, tested it and fiddle links not playing videos, console error: TypeError: $(...).parent(...).child is not a function

Comment: Thanks for your time